# javascripts regex for username, no spacing, no symbol, need to be alphanumeric, no consecutive letters more than 2 in one row

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to write a regular expression to validate a username which must meet the following criteria:

1. Needs to be alphanumeric, with at least one numeric digit
2. no symbols or spaces (only alphanumeric).
3. no runs of consecutive identical characters with more than two in a row.
4. Contain at least 8 characters.

here the thing i have try

```
\^(?=.*\d)((.)\2?(?!\2))+.{8,}$\
```

aaa -> not match.

jjumper13 -> match.

@aabfrff -> not match.

abdirahm1 -> match.

tryand err -> not match.

666abcde -> not match.

bBb123bBb -> not match.

Comment: You need to provide examples of the kind of inputs you're expecting.

Comment: The English in your spec leaves a lot of ambiguity. "alphanumeric OR at least one number"? Do you mean "alphanumeric AND at least one number"? "No symbol" means alphanumeric only, or....? What does "minimum character is 8 in one row" mean? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Does `666` count as "consecutive letters"?

Comment: You wrote `(?=.*\d)` does that mean that you intend for at least one numeric digit to be included?

Comment: 666 yes also  count as consecutive letters  and  (?=.*\d) yes, at least one

Comment: Does `bBb` count also as consecutive identical characters? (are usernames case sensitive?)

Comment: patrick parker - bBb also include as consecutive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, you can use a negative lookahead to fail a specific pattern and just remember to be explicit about the allowed characters - [here's the Regex101 breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/1gS578/1).

```js
const re = /^(?=.*\d)(?!.*(.)\1\1)[a-z\d]{8,}$/i

const controlTests = [
    'abcd0ef', // fail, too few
    'abcdefgh', // fail, no digit
    'abcd0efg', // pass
    'aBcD0eFg', // pass
    'abcd!0ef', // fail, invalid char
    'aAbBcC00', // pass
    'aAbBc000', // fail, too many consecutive (number)
    'aAbBbC00'  // fail, too many consecutive (letter / case-insensitive)
]

const providedTests = [
    'aaa', // fail
    'jjumper13', // pass
    '@aabfrff', // fail
    'abdirahm1', // pass
    'tryand err', // fail
    '666abcde', // fail
    'bBb123bBb' // fail
]

;[].concat(controlTests, providedTests)
    .forEach(input => console.log(`"${input}"`, re.test(input)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it *have* to be a regex? I suspect it'll be easier to maintain as several separate rules (which may internally use regex anyway, but each one should be simpler).